# Can I tell if folders in two different 7zip files are identical?

Tags: 7-zip

I have two 7zip files: `A.7z` and `B.7z` Is it possible to know if folder `X` in both archives are the same, and if not, how do they differ?
I know I can simply extract both folders and compare them but I was wondering if there's a quicker way to do this?

Comment: Which platform are we talking about? *nix or windows?

Comment: Either ;) I have Windows 10 and Arch Linux on my system. I'm currently using Arch but can reboot in to Windows if need be.

Comment: For Arch, you can certainly install [p7zip](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=p7zip), unzip the files to [/tmp](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.html#TMPTEMPORARYFILES), do a `diff -bur dir1/ dir2/` and delete the directories.

Comment: Is this the only way? I was thinking I might have to extract them but was wondering if there's any metadata of some sort inside the 7zip files that could potentially be compared, since this would be considerably faster than extracting both archives.

Comment: There is a command, the 'fc' or file compare; e.g. c:>fc a.7z b.7z. But since they are zipped/compressed, the contents might be unrecognizable on a readable basis. However, if they are the same you will get a message stating that.

Comment: @ejbytes I know the files are different (just checking the file size tells me that), I want to know how they are different.

Comment: I am not sure if that is the only way. There might some other method that doesn't require unzipping, which I am not aware of.

Comment: I suspect you might be able to tell **if** the folders/files were the same by running some form of hash comparison, probably file by file since the sequence might be different.  That wouldn't require extracting the contents.  How they differ is another story, but you wouldn't need to go there if they were the same, so only non-matching ones would need extraction.

Comment: 'fc' = file compare; If file a.txt reads Hi, and b.txt reads Hello, fc output = a 'Hi', b 'Hello'. Just know that it exists and you can use it in the future. It's a compare command and will tell you the differences; how A differs from B. But  like I said compressed files use a type of encryption code for duplicate information and the readability will suffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you try out BeyondCompare:
http://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php

It has a free trial.
It will compare compressed archives and their content.
When installed, it adds an option to file manager context menu, so it's as simple as select the two files, right-click and select the compare option.

(I am not in any way connected to ScooterSoftware, and I'm not sure what the policy is here about commercial software... but I don't care, BeyondCompare is amazing.)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your questions and comments, the answer is no.  You cannot compare them without decompressing the files and folders.  They key is that you said in the comments under your question that "I know the files are different."  Since the files are compressed, the contents of the files are unknown until they are decompressed.

Jehad's answer might work, however I havent tried it.  However, it cannot compare the files without extracting them.  It would not be possible.